# VBA code to refer to a range on another sheet in a separate closed workbook, and perform operations on the referred cells

Tags: vba, excel

This is a snippet of  my code

```
    answer = MsgBox("To get the December KPI values from the previous year folder click Yes, if you want to go to default path, click No and If you are not sure, click Cancel", vbYesNoCancel + vbQuestion, "User Specified Path")
    If answer = vbYes Then

        MyFile = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files,*.xl*;*.xm*")

        Set wkb = Workbooks.Open(MyFile, UpdateLinks:=0)

        'Searching for Month KPI values of previous year December


TryAgain: xName = InputBox("Enter sheet name to find in the workbook: )", "Sheet search")

        If xName = "" Or xName = False Then Exit Sub
        found = False

            On Error Resume Next
            Sheets(xName).Activate

            If ActiveSheet.Name = xName Then
            MsgBox ("Sheet Found")
            found = True

            For j = 3 To 17


                Wb.Sheets(Name).Cells(16, j).Formula = "=(R[-13]C-'" & MyFile & xName & "'!R[-13]C)/'" & MyFile & xName & "'!R[-13]C"
                Wb.Sheets(Name).Cells(17, j).Formula = "=(R[-13]C-'" & xName & "'!R[-13]C)/'" & xName & "'!R[-13]C"
                Wb.Sheets(Name).Cells(18, j).Formula = "=(R[-13]C-'" & xName & "'!R[-13]C)/'" & xName & "'!R[-13]C"
                Wb.Sheets(Name).Cells(19, j).Formula = "=(R[-13]C-'" & xName & "'!R[-13]C)/'" & xName & "'!R[-13]C"
                Wb.Sheets(Name).Cells(20, j).Formula = "=(R[-13]C-'" & xName & "'!R[-13]C)/'" & xName & "'!R[-13]C"
                Wb.Sheets(Name).Cells(21, j).Formula = "=R[-12]C -'" & xName & "'!R[-12]C"
                Wb.Sheets(Name).Cells(22, j).Formula = "=R[-9]C -'" & xName & "'!R[-9]C"
                Wb.Sheets(Name).Cells(23, j).Formula = "=IFERROR(((R[-9]C- '" & xName & "'!R[-9]C)/'" & xName & "'!R[-9]C),0)"

            Next j

            wkb.Close

            End If


           If found = False Then
            If MsgBox("Worksheet name does not exist, click OK to try again or Click Cancel to Exit", vbOKCancel) _
            = vbCancel Then Exit Sub
            GoTo TryAgain

            End If
```

I want to refer the sheet named `Month KPI Dec16` from another workbook named `Group View_2016.xlsx` in a different folder named `2016`. 
The main problem is in the for loop in the `TryAgain` snippet. I want to perform the following operation in my current sheet :

```
Wb.Sheets(Name).Cells(16, j).Formula = "=(R[-13]C-'" & MyFile & xName & "'!R[-13]C)/'" & MyFile & xName & "'!R[-13]C"
```

by referring the cells from the source sheet. I can't figure out how to tweak this particular formula to get it to refer the sheet.

This is the resultant formula that is getting applied in the cell by writing the above code:

```
=(C3-'E:\John\2016\[Group View_2016.xlsxMonth KPI Dec16]Group View_2016'!C3)/'E:\John\2016\[Group View_2016.xlsxMonth KPI Dec16]Group View_2016'!C3
```

whereas I need it as :

```
 =(C3-'E:\John\2016\[Group View_2016.xlsx]Month KPI Dec16'!C3)/'E:\John\2016\[Group View_2016.xlsx]Month KPI Dec16'!C3
```

Need to delete the last bit `]Group View_2016` and shift the `]` to before `Month KPI Dec16`.

Can someone help me with this? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you have set the wkb object you can change your MyFile variable with the following, that should put it all into the correct format:

```
MyFile = wkb.path & "\[" & wkb.name & "]"
```

Comment: I would add a pair of `'` around the filename to be safe.

Comment: There shouldn't be any need to, the formula already includes them around the full file path and name

Comment: @Dave Thanks! You're a lifesaver :) It works perfectly.

Comment: I need to refer data from another sheet named IncomeStatement Dec16 as well, but it doesn't work if I write the code for it within the same TryAgain snippet. I am using xName as the input box for the above question but I want to use yName as the input box for the current question. Is there any way to include it within TryAgain or is there another method to do this?